# React unit test with spyOn on useState is not calling mocked function as it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm learning about testing in React, I have a component with input to write what to search, a select box to select where to search and a button to order by whats selected in the select box.

I made a test to check if when I changed the option of select box, to see if it called the setFilterBy function. It goes inside the function and changes as predicted from "title" to "author" but it doesn't detect the call of the mocked function. Anyone knows whats wrong with this?

Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

interface Props {
    handleFilterChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, filterBy: string) => void
    handleSortClick: (filterBy: string) => void
    total: number
    filtered: number
}

export const PostFilter: React.FC<Props> = ({ handleFilterChange, handleSortClick, total, filtered }) => {
    const [filterBy, setFilterBy] = useState<string>("title")

    const handleSelect = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        console.log("a")
        setFilterBy(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <label> Filter </label>
            <input className="search-input" type="text" name="search" onChange={event => handleFilterChange(event, filterBy)}/>
            <span style={{ padding: "4px" }}>{ filtered > 0 && `${total - filtered} posts found.` } </span>
            By
            <select className="search-type" style={{ margin: "4px" }} value={filterBy} onChange={handleSelect}>
                <option value="title">Title</option>
                <option value="author">Author</option>
            </select>
            <button className="sort-button" onClick={event => handleSortClick(filterBy)}> Sort </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Test

```
import React from "react"
import { mount } from "enzyme"
import { PostFilter } from "./PostFilter"

const handleFilterChange = jest.fn()
const handleSortClick = jest.fn()
const setState = jest.fn()

describe("PosFilter", () => {
    let wrapper

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(initState => [initState, setState]);

        wrapper = mount(
            <PostFilter handleFilterChange={handleFilterChange} handleSortClick={handleSortClick} total={10} filtered={4} /> 
        );
    });

    it("Changing select button should call setState", () => {
        const select = wrapper.find(".search-type")
        expect(select.instance().value).toBe("title")
        wrapper.find(".search-type").simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: "author"
            }
        })
        expect(select.instance().value).toBe("author")
        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
});
```

Result:

```
console.log src/components/threads/PostFilter.tsx:15
      a
```

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be testing if `useState` has been used within your component. Tests should ensure the behaviour of the component is the expected one, without taking into account its implementation details.

In this particular case, you use `useState` to control the value of the `select` element, and you are already testing that once the user selects a new value, its `value` property changes accordingly:

```
it("Changing select button updates its value", () => {
    const select = wrapper.find('.search-type');
    expect(select.prop('value')).toBe('title');

    select.simulate('change', {
        target: {
            value: 'author'
        }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.search-type').prop('value')).toBe('author');
});
```

That should be it as far as the test goes. If you later change the implementation to set the `value` property in the `select` but maintain its functionality (say, for example, that you change your component and define it as a class component and use the `setState` method within the class to update the `select` value), the test will continue to work.

That being said, if you still want to check if `useState` is being used, you will have to mock the whole react module with [jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) at the start of your test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { PostFilter } from '../PostFilter';

const handleFilterChange = jest.fn();
const handleSortClick = jest.fn();
const setState = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react', () => {
    const actualReact = jest.requireActual('react');

    return {
        ...actualReact,
        useState: jest.fn()
    };
});

describe('PosFilter', () => {
    let wrapper;


    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(initState => [initState, setState]);

        wrapper = mount(
            <PostFilter
                handleFilterChange={handleFilterChange}
                handleSortClick={handleSortClick}
                total={10}
                filtered={4}
            /> 
        );
    });

    it('Changing select button should call setState', () => {
        const select = wrapper.find('.search-type');
        expect(select.prop('value')).toBe('title');

        select.simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: 'author'
            }
        });
        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(setState).toHaveBeenCalledWith('author');
    });
});
```

Note that now you can't check if the value of your `select` element has changed, because you are mocking the returned method in `useState`. This causes that when the mock version is called, the default behaviour (updating the state and re-rendering the component) does not take place.

Comment: If you're using `jest.mock()` you don't need `jest.spyOn()` since you can add the implementation on `useState: jest.fn(initState => [initState, setState]))`.

It seems the actual issue that the OP came across is the one discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165138/how-to-mock-spy-usestate-hook-in-jest.